Problem with size parent element that has image less than 100% inside
This is my default look with all images set to 100% width:
enter image description here
These images must have different height and width because they have to keep ratio. Because of that I can not use size with px, vw, etc. - only precents.
If I set images width to 60%, it looks like that:
enter image description here
Images have 60% width but parent element still has 100% width.
How can I make the parent having the same width than image?
<div class="casing">
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="PK.png"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK</span></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="PK-PW2.png"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="PK2W-PW2.png"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK2W+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

I tried with:
.casing__item {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 0;
}
.casing__item > div {
    width: auto;
}
.casing__item img {
    width: 60%;
}

.casing__item {
    display: table;
}
.casing__item > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.casing__item img {
    width: 60%;
}


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Use inline-flex?

From what I can understand from your post, you want to be able to make a row of images smaller or larger while retaining their natural aspect ratio and remaining matched in height? Then just specify the height and let the width remain as auto.
If I have misunderstood your post, please edit it to make your requirements clearer.


.casing {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

.c2 img {
  height: 100px;
}

.c3 img {
  height: 50px;
}

.c4 img {
  height: 25vw;
}
<p>image height not specified ... images are displayed at their intrinsic size</p>
<div class="casing c1">
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK</span></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK2W+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>image height specified as 100px</p>
<div class="casing c2">
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK</span></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK2W+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>image height specified as 50px</p>
<div class="casing c3">
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK</span></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK2W+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>image height specified as a proportion of viewport width for a responsive result</p>
<div class="casing c4">
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK</span></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="casing__item">
        <div class="item__icon"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100"></div>
        <div class="item__label"><span>PK2W+PW2</span></div>
    </div>
</div>



